# If$ \sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, then why does $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$ and not $|x^3|$?

Tags: radicals

Since $\sqrt{x^6}=\sqrt{(x^3)^2}$, wouldn't $\sqrt{(x^3)^2}=|x^3|$?

Comment: You are right, $\sqrt{x^6}=|x^3|$.

Comment: Is there some more context? Where did you find $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$? It is generally true that $\sqrt{x^6}=|x^3|$ as you write.

Comment: http://imgur.com/w1sovub

Comment: It does say "for any nonnegative real number $a$" in that image. Presumably, the remainder should also be read in the context of nonnegative reals.

Comment: And do have a look at first bolded line in that image where it says "we assume no radicals involve negative quantities raised to even powers".

Answer (score 1):

Of course. 
$$
\sqrt{((-2)^3)^2}=\sqrt{(-8)^2}=\sqrt{8^2}=8=|(-2)^3|.
$$